# Can't push due to organization's requirement for 2 factor authentication

Tags: github

I belong to an organization that requires 2 factor authentication, and now I can't push anything - not to the organization's repo, and not to my own personal repos. What do I do now?

And why does it work like this ???

Comment: Enable https://github.com/blog/1614-two-factor-authentication. There is no harm in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when 2FA is activated, you can go to your [PAT Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) page, and [generate one](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) that you will use for pushing: it will replace your password.

```
git push
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

> why does it work like this?

With 2FA, your password is supposed to be protected, because anyone managing to steal that first factor (password) would still need to know a second factor to use it.